# TIP120 LED strip dimming with flickering problem + questions delay

Tags: arduino, transistors, led, potentiometer, led-strip

I need some help with my Arduino program.

Let me introduce the hardware and the goal.

- There is two white LED strip each one of them are controlled by TIP120 transistor.
- There is an potentiometer to set-up manually the full brightness value of the fade effect.

So, when The PIR sensor detect an human the first LED stip fade effect to the maximum brightness thanks to the potentiometer value read before. The second one has its fade-in effect just after the first LED strip.

The LED strips are on for 6 seconds after power on and each are extinguished with fadeout effect.

Problem:

When the first LED strip finish to fade-out it stays slightly on. How to fix this?

Video to show the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3Nwi.jpg

Moreover I noticed below the value 100 for fade-in/fade-out, the LED strips flickering slightly, how to fix that?

Delay question:

-As you can see there is an little delay for the second LED strip power. How to remove this delay and power it directly when the first LED strip have finish his fadein?

- I would like to know, how to start the second LED strip at the same time like the first one but with a difference of a second than the first.

If you have any suggestion to improve my code you are welcome!

The code:

```
int PIR = 4;              // the pin that the sensor is atteched to
int TR = 3;               // the pin that the TIP 120 Base is atteched to for the first led strip
int TRB = 5;              // the pin that the TIP 120 Base is atteched to for the second led strip
int ledDelay = 5000;          //time to wait untill light switch off
int pwm;

void setup() {
  pinMode(PIR, INPUT);    // initialize sensor as an input
  pinMode(TR, OUTPUT);    // initialize TIP 120 as an output
  pinMode(TRB, OUTPUT);   // initialize TIP 120 as an output
  Serial.begin(9600);     // initialize serial
}

void loop(){
      pwm = analogRead (A7);
      pwm = map(pwm, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
     Serial.println(pwm);
  if (digitalRead(PIR) == HIGH) { // check if the sensor is HIGH
     Serial.println("Motion detected!");
  for(int fadeValue = 0 ; fadeValue <= pwm; fadeValue +=5) {

    // sets the value (range from 0 to 255):
    analogWrite(TR, fadeValue);       
    // wait for 60 milliseconds to see the dimming effect   
    delay(60);  // turn LED ON
    }

 delay(100);  
     ///

  for(int fadeValue = 0 ; fadeValue <= pwm; fadeValue +=5) {

    // sets the value (range from 0 to 255):
    analogWrite(TRB, fadeValue);       
    // wait for 60 milliseconds to see the dimming effect   
    delay(60);  
    }
  delay(100); 

    ///
        delay(ledDelay); //time to wait untill light switch off
    for(int fadeValue = pwm ; fadeValue >= 0; fadeValue -=5) {
    // sets the value (range from 0 to 255):
    analogWrite(TR, fadeValue);       
    // wait for 60 milliseconds to see the dimming effect   
    delay(60);
            } 
    for(int fadeValue = pwm ; fadeValue >= 0; fadeValue -=5) {
    // sets the value (range from 0 to 255):
    analogWrite(TRB, fadeValue);       
    // wait for 60 milliseconds to see the dimming effect   
    delay(60);
            } 
            }     

  else {
    digitalWrite(TR, LOW);       // turn LED 1 OFF
    digitalWrite(TRB, LOW);       // turn LED 2 OFF
    Serial.println("Motion stopped!");
    delay(100);                   // delay 100 milliseconds
  }
}
```

Picture of schematic

[image]

Note :

- The led strip I used are 5V 3528 warm white not rgb
- Power supply of led strip is a step down converter on 12V battery(setting on 5V 2A).

Comment: Please provide a schematic for you circuit

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! _"introduce the hardware"_ This is where a schematic comes in. EE talks in schematics. If you click on edit and the schematic symbol, a competent schematics editor will open up. If you already have one from your e-CAD of choise, please post a picture of that.

Comment: Schematic added, please check :)

Comment: Tinkercad is not a schematic, and your tinkercad does not even match what you show in your video.  I see issues in the tinkercad (e.g. resistors are shorted) that don't appear to be an issue in real life.

Comment: +1 on what @mbedded said. Please click on edit and the schematic symbol and draw there.

Comment: Do you understand your code? Your code sometimes doesn't fade out all the way to 0. The LEDs are just doing what you tell them. The flicker is probably unavoidable though.

Comment: It's hard to match the reality with tinkercad, I did as I could and some parts like the arduino uno or white led strip are not on the software.
I want to clarify that I am a beginner
About the resistances they are wired like that in reallity.
What is not clear about my image?

Yes i understand my code but it may have somes mistake,  please can you help me?

Comment: I tried to draw a diagram with the softwareof the site but it lacks elements like the arduino or the pir sensor.

Comment: About flickering I notice If I unplug 1 led strip , it no longer appears.

Comment: Remove the delay(100); to remove the delay between the fade in of TR and TRB. As for the flicker. What is your resistor value? 10k?

Comment: You can make custom components for them. The symbol for such devices are not terribly important.

Comment: @Passerby
Done, it's better and thanks to the code of Bil now there is no problem with fade 
Anyways, there is still flicker  problem
My resistor value is an 10K right

Comment: @winny I'll try but I'm no expert haha

Comment: Is the power supply enough? If you take off half the load and flicker goes away. There is also issues with the analogwrite and some pins and low values and delay as they share a timer. See the bottom of https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/

Comment: @Cypf Thinkercad and Fritzing "drawings" are not a "schematic". They are worth for a newbie, because they reproduce the real appearance of the circuit in real world. But those colored drawings of a breadboard are not a good option for giving a real understanding of the circuit. The eyes of the competent folks here at EE.SE can't even look at those drawings. Please, if you want to stay and learn with this hobby, **teach yourself how to see and interpret real electronic schematics.** A schematic is the best way of understanding a circuit, and is also the best way of getting help here.

Comment: @Cypf, although your problem was solved, there's something left to be said: specially if you are a newbie, don't try to do all those things at the same time. PIR sensors, two LED strips controled by transistors, a code for fading LEDs. Try to use each one of those things separatedly. First, PIR sensors and a single LED. Second, only the transistors and the strips; third, the transistors, the strips, and the fading; and so on. This kind approach will make things easier.

Comment: @mguima who decided an old schematic style is the best way of understanding a circuit or that we "folk can't even look at those drawings".

Comment: @Passerby I didn't "decided" anything. What I said is, of course, just my personal opinion, based on my own observations of the repeated situations where a noob OP post those drawings, and some of the EE.SE multi-thousand-score pundits teach OP that Fritzing and Thinkercad drawings are not a schematic. Maybe those observations can be somewhat biased by my own restrictions with those drawings. And I humbly think that the fact that engineering texts haven't adopted those drawings is a good indication that orthodox schematics are still the best way of understanding the design of a circuit.

Answer (score 3):

1. Format your code with Ctrl+T. it is than easier to read
2. Write in after "fade out"      analogWrite(TR, 0);

The fadeout value has in 4 of 5 cases still a value in it.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your comment
You learn me something with Ctrl+T function.
I write like this : 

    for (int fadeValue = pwm ; fadeValue >= 0; fadeValue -= 5) {
      // sets the value (range from 0 to 255):
      analogWrite(TRB, fadeValue);
      // wait for 60 milliseconds to see the dimming effect
      delay(60);
      analogWrite(TRB, 0);

Comment: Now it's working perfectly thanks, do you know to solve the flickering problem ?
I notice If I unplug 1 led strip , it no longer appears.

Comment: @Cypf, the correct practice of thanking here in EE.SE is marking the answer as accepted, in order to Bill get his deserved reputation score points.

Comment: @mguima correct practice is to wait to allow others to answer instead of immediately marking the first partial answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @Cypf Is your powersupply to weak or the current limition to low?

Comment: @Passerby 1) OP said that **the answer solved his problem**, so, I don't see why OP should wait for another answer. I don't ever see why would someone write another answer if OP has said that his problem was solved. 2) My comment saying "mark the answer as useful before asking for further explanation" was made strictly accordingly with [item 8 of this meta anser](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5848/102626). 3) When I wrote that comment, I really expected that one of the multi-thousand pundits (like you) would not let that comment from an outsider go ahead freely...

Comment: 4) Isn't kind of funny that what I said was taken directly from the words of one of the multi-thousand pundits, maybe the king of them? But I understand and I even expected that, if those same words comes apparently from the "mouth" of an outsider, they would rise an "correction", as you did. ;-) 5) By the way, OP didn't showed up here since then, so, @Bill didn't get the recognition he deserved from his useful, albeit simple, answer.

Comment: Not sure what you're alluding to there, @mguima, but Passerby is right that correct practice is to wait to allow others to answer instead of marking a first partial answer as the accepted one. Any OP may change their opinion of what fully answers their question when they read further answers. Any poster of an existing answer is then free to read them then expand and improve their own answer as they wish.

Comment: @Passerby, I mean.

Comment: @mguima 8 says upvote before asking, while 9 explicitly says to wait to accept as the answer. So idk what to tell you, your own evidence contradicts you.

Comment: @TonyM and Passerby :-) You're right, and I'm wrong! You both can be happy, now! My mistake was that I said that OP could "accept", but I should have say that OP could "upvote". BTW, when I wrote that comment, the question had 0 score (I was the first to upvote it). I didn't know - untill two minutes ago - that an OP can upvote **AND** accept the same answer. In this question, it seems that OP of this question didn't "accept", NEITHER "upvoted". But, I'm really sorry for my mistake. ;-)

Comment: @mguima, oh good, that's that sorted - nothing personal by anyone and no harm done, it's only an engineering site. Peace reigns again :-)